# Sum of series: $1^1 + 2^2 + 3^3 + … + n^n$

Tags: summation, exponentiation

Searched every where on web but I couldn't find out the formula for this series.

That's why I am asking here.

I tried following following formula:

$((n*(n+1))/2)^n$

Comment: There is unlikely to be a formula for this series simpler than the series itself.  Not everything has a formula.

Comment: Try with $n=3$ ; the expression in the title gives $1+4+27=32$ while what you tried gives $36$. This looks very much like Somophore's dream. There is no closed form.

Comment: A good approximation is simply $n^n$.

Comment: Only formula is to manually calculate.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence of partial sums is on the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A001923), but no simple formula is listed there, which makes me think no such formula is known.