# Is there any general formula for the sequence $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n k^k$?

Tags: summation

I have faced this series several times. Could it be possible to come up with a formula for the following sequence?

$S_n= \sum_{k=1}^n k^k = 1^1 + 2^2 + 3^3 + \ldots + n^n$

If yes, then what is that and how it could be proved?

Note: I had come through [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119636/formula-for-calculating-sum-n-0mnrn) which I have found almost near to this series but still could not come up.

Comment: The word series usually means the infinite sum, you should just use sum (or summation) here .

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Could I use the word `sequence`? because, pluses are already indicating that it is a summation.

Comment: First rule of 'is there a formula for this sequence?' : try OEIS.  In this case, plugging the first half-dozen values in yields http://oeis.org/A001923 , which doesn't have any information about a simpler closed form, making it highly unlikely that one is known.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Thats a good point. But could we tell that there does not exist a formula for the sequence? Thanks

Comment: Yes, sequence is fine (i.e, "the sequence $s_n=\sum_{k=1}^n k^k$").

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Thanks, updated.

Comment: @manetsus There are almost no tools for being able to say 'a formula does not exist for this sequence' - sometimes you can use growth rates to eliminate formulae of a specific kind, but in a case like this that sort of approach isn't really available.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Well, I guess we could just say "this sequence grows as $x^x$" or something like that, to give an estimate.

Comment: @DietrichBurde $k!\ne k^k$, why do you keep trying to close these as dupes?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I am sorry, retracted! Took the wrong cut and paste. I meant [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2050078/is-there-any-kind-of-formula-to-estimate-this-112233-nn?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Another one is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1514073/sum-of-series-11-22-33-nn?noredirect=1&lq=1).